# Play animation through an image array

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have about 200 photos that will run in a loop, there will be a fade-i and a fade-out between the images, is there any way to work with an array of images or something like that so I do not apply the same animation for all the images one by one?

### Edit

I've tried this, but it don't respect my `setInterval`:

```
import fl.transitions.*;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import flash.events.Event;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, sendToBack);

function sendToBack(event:Event):void{
    setInterval(function(){
        setChildIndex(getChildAt(2), 0);

        var my_mc = getChildAt(2);

        getChildAt(1).visible = false;
        getChildAt(0).visible = false;

        TransitionManager.start(my_mc, {
            type: Fade
        });
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Well how to answer this? Whats your plan? To avoid `"same animation for all images one by one"` just use one function that fades in/out any specified image. Look up **as3 function parameters** (to specify target image) and also a tweening class like BetweenAS3, Caurina or Greensocks. Those would automate things like fades for you over specific time. There is loading text files to read a list of filenames and just read/load by each line...

Comment: @VC.One look at my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the desired result with this code:

```
import fl.transitions.*;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import flash.events.Event;

var childsNum = numChildren,
    frameInterval = 3000,
    fadeDuration = 0.5;

function hideAll(){
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < numChildren; i++) { 
        getChildAt(i).visible = false;
    }
}

hideAll();

function animateFrame(){

    var child = getChildAt(childsNum - 1),
    myTM:TransitionManager = new TransitionManager(child);

    myTM.startTransition({
        type: Fade,
        duration: fadeDuration
    });

    myTM.addEventListener("allTransitionsInDone", function(){
        setChildIndex(getChildAt(childsNum - 1), 0);
        getChildAt(1).visible = false;
    });
}

setInterval(function(){
    animateFrame();
}, frameInterval);
```